# When I click my visited days, calendar opens on January 2014

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page, visited-days, calendar

As in topic, when I click in my profile on "visited" it shows up with a calendar but opened on January 2014, not like every other time on current month.

I'm using chrome atm.

[image]

In my opinion this issue is correctable, you can provide jQ calendar with current date taken from server, not from the local computer. And it's not unreproducable - you can reproduce it while changing computer's local date.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome

Comment: Are you certain your computer clock is correctly configured?

Comment: You were right, I got wrong date in my computer's clock, though in my opinion this bug shouldn't have showed up from such a reason.

Comment: It youses your client date to select the current month - looks like a jQ Calendar, so why not

Comment: Well as far as I know jQ calendar can open on a certain date - which can be generated serverside

Comment: Good job minusing it without any commentary.

Comment: In all fairness it seems insanely difficult for the OP to realise this is a local side problem, -4 seems a little harsh

Comment: Well I realised pretty fast when someone stated it in the comments. But still no one explained to me why is that not a wrong way to do this with depending on client side not server side

Comment: @KeluThatsall I agree, and have included an answer to that effect

Comment: @KeluThatsall, downvotes work a little differently on meta, in this case it probably just means that somebody tried to replicate and couldn't.

Comment: @RichardTingle: BS.  It would be the absolute first thing I'd check.

Comment: How would your system clock be different without you knowing? If a wrong date shows up surely you would make an instant connection..

Answer (score 6):

Given that the entire site is based upon UTC (in this case visited days are not based on local time days but on UTC days) it makes sense for the calendar to open such that the current stack exchange day is displayed, not the local day.

At present at month ends/starts it could occur that the calendar opens on a month before/after the true stack exchange month meaning your visit today is not displayed even if the user’s local time is correctly set.

As such I support this being based on server time not local time

Comment: Thank you ;) Even though I agree it's just a minor issue I felt really bad when everyone just minused me like hell without explaining when all I did was try to help correct the site.

Comment: It sounds more like a feature request than a bug, when described like that.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the date from the server would give incorrect results because of time zones. The server could give you 2013-11-30 while in your location it's already 2013-12-01.

Depending on the client's date is correct.

Comment: As far as I know you need to set your time zone in your profile, so serversidewise - you know what is the exact date on client's side.

Comment: Where would that be? You can enter your location, but you can type in anything you like.

Comment: @KeluThatsall There is no timezones in Stack Exchange profiles. We just give OpenID and that's it. (only the email is taken from there, no other data)

Comment: Oh to be honest I was convinced it can be set up in profile

Comment: Giving the UTC day not the local day would be correct behaviour as all the information on that calendar is based on UTC (that being visited days)